# Kohana 3 ORM: advanced queries, efficiency

Tags: php, orm, kohana, kohana-3

So we all know that the documentation for Kohana 3 is absolutely horrible. So how can I construct the following query, where I have a "Player" and "Dragon" model?

```
SELECT * FROM `dragons` JOIN `players` ON (`dragons`.`player_id` = `players`.`player_id`) WHERE `uid` IN (1,2,3) ORDER BY `dragons`.`id` ASC
```

I can use `ORM::factory('dragon')->join("players")->on("dragons.player_id", "=", "players.player_id")` to get to the join part, but I can't do the `in` clause. There's no `in` function in Kohana 3's ORM. I tried the `where` function, but it puts quotes around the third parameter, so my list of IDs becomes a string and the query becomes invalid. So what can I do? I can't figure out how to add custom bits of SQL to my ORM loading queries. Again, because documentation doesn't exist.

The only way I can think of right now is to just load all the appropriate players, loop through them, and fetch their dragons. But this seems really stupid - way more queries than necessary. I've felt like this before, that using ORM makes things horribly inefficient on the querying end, in order to make it slightly easier to code. Is this true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ORM can produce some less than desirable queries - but it also speeds development time and gives you an abstraction (some people feel they should never have to write SQL by hand anymore).

Most of the time I prefer SQL in complicated web applications.

However, in saying that, what you want is possible using Kohana 3's ORM.

---

From [The Pixel Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85616/the-pixel-developer).

```
where('field', 'IN', range(1, 3));
```

This has the advantage of not having the loop. :-)

Comment: @The Pixel Developer: yes, it is possible

Comment: @The Pixel Developer You turned my mediocre answer into a good one - thanks!

Comment: No problem alex. Not really worth its own answer for 3 lines and since you already did most of the work I'd thought it'd be better to improve yours :)

Comment: ok, so if the third where() parameter is a string, it gets stringified in the query, but if it's an array, it's good? thanks!

Comment: @Tesserex [Apparently](https://github.com/kohana/database/blob/3.0.x/classes/kohana/database/query/builder/where.php#L40) :P